# Wacom pen small tablet ctl-490/b isn't recongnized

Tags: drivers, tablet, wacom

I have ubuntu version 14.04 on my laptop.
When plugged my wacom pen into the usb drive the led light turned on but the tablet isn't working and not recognized by my laptop. (the cursor doesn't react when moving the pen.

when entering the following command:  sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)

got the error message:

**Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
Package linux-headers-3.11.0-17-generic is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'linux-headers-3.11.0-17-generic' has no installation candidate**

the tablet is not detected in the settings either

Answer (score 0):

You should now be able to install the driver using the ppa package I've put together here for 14.04:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wacom/LatestDriver

Please follow the instructions and report any issues or errors here.